# Stereo Spread on a 3.2 Channel System

Tags: mixing, speakers, phase, stereo-imaging

I just set up a new speaker system in my work place.  It is a 3.2 Channel system with three center speakers (left, center, right) and two subs.

These are used to play music so the input audio is typically stereo.  Listener sits in the center of the system.

Typically I would mix these like so:

```
 Left Speaker(L input) / Center Channel (LRsum) / Right Channel (R)
```

However, I'm curious about increasing the stereo spread on this setup.  Currently I have them programmed like this:

```
Left Speaker(LRsum + (-R)) / Center Channel (LRsum) / Right Channel(LRsum+(-L))
```

To clarify further, the Left channel is now playing the left right sum minus the phase inverted right channel.  The Center Channel is now playing the left right sum.  The Right channel is now playing the left right sum minus the phase inverted left channel.

My thinking here is that summing the L and R channels like this will entirely cancel out anything panned L or Center and play only audio hard panned left during production.

**So here is my question:**

If I take a LR mix and sum that with a phase inverted R, does that leave me with only the hard panned L content?

Happy to clarify any part of this.

Comment: LRsum + (-R) = L input and LRsum + (-L) = R input, so that will not change anything at all. Elements that have not been hard panned will only partially be cancelled out by including the opposite channel phase inverted, so they will still appear to be in the same location in the sound field.

Comment: Ok.  What about this then:  (LR + L) + (-LR) = hard panned L?  Looks like that might just result in the same thing.  I'm really just trying to find a way to subtract anything panned center in my L/R speaker.